# How to achieve multiple records output with based on single record

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table "Managers" that contains data as follows

[image]

i am expecting the output like as below

[image]

or another output format i am expecting is 
[image]

The conditions are 
manager 1001 is joined in 2018 and end date is 9999, so he is active in 2018, 2019 and 2020

manager 1004 is joined in 2018 and he left the company in the same year, so he is active only in 2018

please help me on how to achieve this

Comment: Why would you want this in separate rows?  The desired results don't really make sense.

Comment: yes i want them in a separate rows, that is the problem i am facing, if i get the 2nd output format is also fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a list of years and `JOIN` with it:

```
SELECT manager_id, yearnum, 'Active' AS status
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(2018, 2020)) AS yearnum
JOIN managers ON yearnum BETWEEN EXTRACT(year FROM eff_start_date)
                             AND EXTRACT(year FROM eff_end_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH years AS (
  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM year) year 
  FROM ( SELECT 
    (SELECT MIN(eff_start_date) FROM `project.dataset.managers`) AS min_date, 
    (SELECT MAX(eff_end_date) FROM `project.dataset.managers` WHERE eff_end_date != '9999-12-31') max_date  
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_TRUNC(min_date, YEAR), DATE_TRUNC(max_date, YEAR), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) year
), managers_list AS (
  SELECT manager_id, status, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eff_start_date) start_year, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eff_end_date) end_year
  FROM `project.dataset.managers`
)
SELECT manager_id, year, status 
FROM years y, managers_list m
WHERE year BETWEEN start_year AND end_year
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.managers` AS (
  SELECT 1001 manager_id, 'Active' status, DATE '2018-02-10' eff_start_date, DATE '9999-12-31' eff_end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 1002, 'Active', '2018-02-14', '2020-12-31' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1003, 'Active', '2018-02-16', '2019-02-15' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1004, 'Active', '2018-02-16', '2018-12-31' 
), years AS (
  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM year) year 
  FROM ( SELECT 
    (SELECT MIN(eff_start_date) FROM `project.dataset.managers`) AS min_date, 
    (SELECT MAX(eff_end_date) FROM `project.dataset.managers` WHERE eff_end_date != '9999-12-31') max_date  
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_TRUNC(min_date, YEAR), DATE_TRUNC(max_date, YEAR), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) year
), managers_list AS (
  SELECT manager_id, status, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eff_start_date) start_year, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eff_end_date) end_year
  FROM `project.dataset.managers`
)
SELECT manager_id, year, status 
FROM years y, managers_list m
WHERE year BETWEEN start_year AND end_year 
-- ORDER BY manager_id, year
```

with result

```
Row manager_id  year    status   
1   1001        2018    Active   
2   1001        2019    Active   
3   1001        2020    Active   
4   1002        2018    Active   
5   1002        2019    Active   
6   1002        2020    Active   
7   1003        2018    Active   
8   1003        2019    Active   
9   1004        2018    Active
```